# is there any wordpress bitcoin plugin can support escrow?

Tags: wordpress, bitcoin

want to use wp make a marketplace which will support bitcoin payment but need a escrow function
does such plugin exist.
when buyer pay bitcoin it will allow escrow when buyer got the goods seller can got bitcoin.
also need the marketplace has function to allow buyer and seller give rating for each other.

Answer (score -1):

You should try this plugin, works with bitcoin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/mycred/

Answer (score -1):

Old question, but Stripe accepts bitcoins. Therefore, look for a plugin that uses stripe gateway. Or make the necessary changes.

Answer (score -1):

try this one

https://wordpress.org/plugins/apirone-bitcoin-forwarding

you can accept bitcoins to your specified address. No registration needed and no KYC.
Just use your own bitcoin address.

Comment: kdiny consider adding more information in your answer